# Show that a subset is a $σ$-Algebra

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I've always had trouble proving that something is a $σ$ -Algebra.

As an example I take this exercise:

Let $X$ be a nonempty set with a $σ$-algebra $A$ and $Z$ a set.

Let $T$ be a map with $T : X \rightarrow Z$ and $A_2:= \left \{  T(B) : B \in A \right \}$. I have to prove if $A_2$ is a $σ$-algebra on $Z$.

I really don't know how to proceed but here is what I have tried:

For me $A_2$ is not a $σ$-algebra on $Z$.

Let $X=\left \{  -1,1 \right \}$ and $Y=\left \{  -1,1,2 \right \}$ and A a $σ$-algebra with $A=P(X)$.

Let $T$ be $T: X \rightarrow Z$ with $T(1)=1, T(-1)=-1$ so since there is no $T(x)=2$, $A_2$ cannot be a $σ$-algebra since $Z\nsubseteq A_2$.

Is what I have tried right? Have I done any error?

Comment: Your analysis is correct and the result supposed to be proven is wrong.

Comment: Nothing wrong. Well done. Here is a  [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554393/show-that-class-of-sets-is-sigma-algebra#comment9579314_4554393) that does produce a $\sigma$-algebra in $Z$.